# Understanding っていうのかな

Tags: grammar

> 「んー……駄目だねこりゃ。<囁告篇帙>自体は情報を検索してるっぽいんだけど、それをあたしに伝える機能が死んでる**っていうのかな**。……」

The speaker was talking to herself. I’m not sure why っていうの is used here. Usually というのか signifies a rhetorical question meaning “Are you saying ...” (which doesn’t fit in the context) and it seems feasible to just say かな in this sentence.

Could you please explain this っていうのかな?

Comment: Btw, I googled 「囁告篇帙」and it appears your line is from [the light novel 『デート・ア・ライブ』](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96). I recommend you cite your source in your questions, just so it'd be easier for people to look up the surrounding context. [Even native speakers have said they could make mistakes in their answers without context.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important)

Comment: @EddieKalEd Thanks for the suggestion. I will cite my source in my question next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 「というのか」usually marks a rhetorical question, but here the sentence ending particle (終助詞) is not 「か」「の」or「だ」. It is a compound (連語) of two particles 「か」「な」. 「かな」is a word all its own, usually translating as "I wonder". 「かな」shouldn't be confused with 「か」.

It makes sense the speaker uses かな in her monologue, much as how people say "I wonder" talking to themselves, with or without listeners. 「って」is a colloquialized 「と」. 「の」is a nominalizer. Nominalization is really common in Japanese. I would interpret this「っていうのかな」as summarizing what's before it and then expressing something like "that thing, hmm..." or "just like that..." In fact, if I were to translate this sentence I don't think I would translate that part, at least not as a sentence ending. I would probably use phrases such as "I heard..." or "the feeling that" to convey the hesitation and indirectness.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a mistake. This sentence is not a monologue. Someone else asked the speaker, “What is the situation with <囁告篇帙>?”

Comment: @chinoalpha In that case, it is probably easier to translate the indirectness. "Maybe" or "I guess" would do.

Comment: Thanks again. I see. So your answer above still stands even if the sentence is not a monologue, doesn’t it? The っていうの part functions like a summary?

Comment: @chinoalpha The nominalization works the same. That part is appended at the end because the speaker doesn't want to sound too assertive. It wraps up the statement that the speaker wishes to make and softens it. It's called hedging language.